# Server Not Found Error in Silverlight using WCF Service(Windows Service)

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight-5.0

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DBConnString" value="Data Source=acdw;Initial Catalog=Trans;User ID=sa;Password=d@t@bas3;Connect Timeout=20" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="PolarisWcfServiceLibrary.PositionExposureAttribute.PositionAttributeDataService" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
        <endpoint address="http://acdwdev01:8085/PolarisWcfServiceLibrary.PositionExposureAttribute.PositionAttributeDataService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="polarisBasicHttpBinding" contract="PolarisWcfServiceLibrary.PositionExposureAttribute.IPositionAttributeDataService"
        />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://acdwdev01:8085/PolarisWcfServiceLibrary.PositionExposureAttribute.PositionAttributeDataService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="polarisBasicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transferMode="Buffered" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I know this is kind of a repeated question but I have tried almost all of the fixes discussed in many threads regarding the same and still haven't found the correct solution.
One of my silverlight application(webhosted in IIS7) is using WCF windows service to fetch data from SQL database and it is working perfectly when hosted in my UAT server. But when hosted the same service in PROD server, it seems whenever I make a request to the service from my silverlight application before I receive the completed event of my previous call from the service, I get communication error: Server not found. But if I wait for my previous call to get complete before making a new request/call to service it works perfectly.

Please suggest what needs to be changed or looked at.

Comment: Please the code / configuration used in your question.
Have you tested it locally in IIS?

Comment: Jérémie, Thanks for you reply. Shared the config settinga and I have tested this in IIS.